# How do I write the dollar value of a particular year in the US?

Tags: expressions

How do I write the dollar value of a particular year in the US?

Is this a standard format?

$6.5 million (US $2005)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This isn't really a question about the English language per se, but about the presentation of a label. For clarity, this is usually represented as something like *2005 dollars* as *$2005* looks too much like an amount; see e.g. the U.S. Census page on [Current versus Constant (or Real) Dollars](https://www.census.gov/topics/income-poverty/income/guidance/current-vs-constant-dollars.html).

Comment: The fact that the amount corresponds to a date is irrelevant. (And how is $6.5 million being calculated as *US $2005*?)

Comment: If you put a dollar sign next to a number, then that number will be read as a dollar amount. So if you put a dollar sign next to something you intend to be interpreted as a year, then that is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More usually one wants to write it from the opposite point of view, as in "Theodore Roosevelt's limousine cost $x ($xyz dollars in 2018)". The scope for confusing readers is very great here, so it is unwise to rely on **any** simple abbreviation. If you are writing something that needs constantly to refer to the value in modern money of specific amounts long ago (or vice versa) then you need to establish for your readers a consistent abbreviation that you use throughout. There is no standard abbreviation.